# Recursion in PythonTutor, IDLE and Spyder

Tags: python, recursion, spyder, python-idle

This recursive function works in Pythontutor.com, but reaches recursion depth limit in IDLE and Spyder. I'm not an expert, so I am puzzled. I do know that the base case is incorrect. I really do.
My question is why IDLE and Spyder create a none returning recursive loop, rather than output that the second power of 4 is 4, as PythonTutor does. It is incorrect, but at least the program completes gracefully.

```
def recPow(base, exp): 
    ''' 
    base: int or float. 
    exp: int >= 0 
    returns: int or float, base^exp 
    '''   
    if exp == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return base * recPow(base, exp-1)

print(recPow(4, 2))
```

Comment: The `if` line should be `if exp == 0:`.  That aside, your code runs and returns 4 on Windows with 3.8 to the future 3.11.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the code posted does not have the behavior described.  It runs and gives the answer expected from the buggy code (see comment).  Not recursion error.

Comment: When ever code does not behave as you expect when running it from an editor or IDE, and you cannot figure out the problem, run it directly with python so as to eliminate the editor or IDE as a possible factor.

Answer (score 0):

I got it now. I did not write a testcase in case exp is assigned 0.
My bad. In the case of zero, this will crash even Pythontutor: The server may be OVERLOADED.